# JupyterBook: change font size for code blocks and regular text

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, jupyterbook

I have a fairly simple jupyterbook project whose structure looks like the image below.

[image]

I was able to control the text justification via a .css file under `_static_` called `myfil.css`. The file looks like this:

[image]

This configuration kicks in automatically when building the project. I don't need to add anything to the `_config.yml` file. Though, I can't seem to be able to modify the text size and, more importantly, the text size within code blocks. I have a few different ways of defining a code block per the guidelines when using the MySt structure (see [here](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/file-types/myst-notebooks.html)).

So the question is: how can I explicitly control the font size of the text within code blocks? I would like this to affect both executable chunks (i.e., `{code-cell} ...`) and just regular blocks (i.e., ``` some code here ```). I don't want the inline code to be affected.

My intuition is that I need to add something in `myfile.css` but just don't know what.